# How do you transfer a socket connection from one socketchannel to another?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, socketchannel

I have a ServerSocketChannel and once this channel accepts a connection I want to "transfer" or "pass" it to a SocketChannel. I have tried, once I have accepted the connection, to simply do a `socketchannel.bind(ServerSocketChannel.socket.getLocalSocketAddress)` but I get an exception that says "Address already in use". Which makes sense so I have tried to save the socket address in a variable, close the ServerSocketChannel, and then attempt to bind it with the variable but it still complains about already being in use.

```
//Accept the connection
ServerSocketChannel.accept();

//Save the address and close the connection
address = ServerSocketChannel.socket().getLocalSocketAddress();
ServerSocketChannel.close();

//Bind the address to another channel
SocketChannel.bind(address);//Here is where I get the exception
```

This is how my solution looks right now(except for the variable names but you get the idea). The reason I can't just accept it with that channel is because it's used for another purpose once this connection has been established, so I need to have dedicated ServerSocketChannel opened just for accepting connections which are then passed to the SocketChannel.

Comment: Needs code.  *Why* do you want to do this?  It feels like an XY problem.  You want to solve problem "Y" but you're saying your problem is "X" -- how to pass a socket channel.  Please describe more what you are actually trying to do.  Normally you just get the accepted channel from the server socket and use that.

Comment: Sure, I edited my original post.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'transfer[ring] a connection from one socket channel to another'. The accepted connection is returned as a `SocketChannel` by `ServerSocketChannel.accept()`, but you are throwing it away. 'I can't just accept it with that channel ... because it's used for another purpose once this connection has been established' is meaningless. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved my problem. I overlooked something simple and tried a longer way instead.
`SocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.accept();`
Is what I was looking for all along.

Comment: *You* just solved it? You were told that twenty-four hours ago. Twice. Credit where credit is due.

Comment: I'm thankful for the answers but I didn't really understand them that well before. I believe you said that "There is no such thing as 'transfer[ring] a connection from one socket channel to another", isn't that exactly what I'm doing with `SocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.accept()`

Comment: No, you are accepting a connected channel from a listening channel. The listening channel doesn't have a connection at all.